# Selecting a lot of entries from different range

Tags: selection, multi-selection

I need a good approach for the user to be able to select a lot of options. The values are going to be numbers only. User should be able to select from example numbers between 1000 and 1050, and 1220 - 1300.

What is the reasonable solution for this? I was thinking in the beginning the multi-selection dropdown, something like this (where you can also select with shift+click):

[image]

But then again I do not think this will work out as there can be hundreds or even thousands numbers that user needs to select.

Should I just fall back the the basic input field where user himself specifies the ranges he wants and separates them with comma or similar, for example like:

1000-1050, 1220-1300

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use a data grid with two columns, From and To. The user may enter as many rows as required.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2felDNi.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I'm a big fan of the [**KISS method**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle), so I'd go with what you say: specify the range with inputs (not necessarily separated by commas, you could also have rows of *from* and *to* inputs, pretty much what DesignerAnalyst suggests, only that using input fields).

However, if you're looking for a visual solution, try something like this:

[image]

The image above is taken from https://github.com/atomiomi/jqueryui-slider-prototype/wiki/jQuery-UI-slider , so you might want to take a look to it as well. Just in case, there are other *multi-range slider* solutions, I just chose this one because the image clearly explains what you need

Comment: Thanks Devin, really good alternative with the more visual approach, I will keep it in mind.